# Sum Until Value Reached - Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

In Teradata, I need a query to first identify all members in the `MEM TABLE` that currently have a negative balance, let's call that `CUR_BAL`. Then, for all of those members only, sum all transactions from the `TRAN TABLE` in order by date until the sum of those transactions is equal to the `CUR_BAL`.

Editing to add a third `ADJ` table that contains `MEM_NBR`, `ADJ_DT` and `ADJ_AMT` that need to be included in the running total in order to capture all of the records.

I would like the outcome to include the `MEM.MEM_NBR`, `MEM.CUR_BAL`, `TRAN.TRAN_DATE` OR `ADJ.ADJ_DT` (date associated with the transaction that resulted in the running total to equal `CUR_BAL`), `MEM.LST_UPD_DT`.  I don't need to know if the balance is negative as a result of a transaction or adjustment, just the date that it went negative.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    mem_nbr,
    cur_bal,
    tran_date,
    tran_type
from (
    select
        a.mem_nbr,
        a.cur_bal,
        b.tran_date,
        b.tran_type,
        a.lst_upd_dt,
        sum(b.tran_amt) over (partition by b.mem_nbr order by b.tran_date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as cumulative_bal
    from mem a
    inner join (
        select
            mem_nbr,
            tran_date,
            tran_amt,
            'Tran' as tran_type
        from tran
        union all
        select
            mem_nbr,
            adj_date,
            adj_amt,
            'Adj' as tran_type
        from adj
    ) b
    on a.mem_nbr = b.mem_nbr
    where a.cur_bal < 0
    qualify cumulative_bal < 0
) z
qualify rank() over (partition by mem_nbr order by tran_date) = 1
```

The subquery picks up all instances where the cumulative balance is negative, then the outer query picks up the earliest instance of it. If you want the latest, add `desc` after tran_date in the final `qualify` line.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am looking for a couple of things. I need the current balance (if it's negative) and the date of their last transaction, as well as the date they went negative, which could have been many transactions ago, so I can investigate why they went negative in the first place. I'll try your response in a bit and post back!! Thanks again!

Comment: edited to add an additional table with Adjustments that I need to consider as well. Not sure how to join on a third table while including those dates in the sequence. Your code worked perfectly on the two tables but didn't return all of the accounts needed because I didn't think about the ADJ table. Can you help with a second join? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't quite understand how your adjustments table works. It would be best if you include some sample data and run through what you expect as the result.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Basically, the Adj table is just like the transaction table except it stores adjustments instead of real transactions. Adjustments modify the ending balance just like an ordinary transaction would. So I guess you could think of it as a second transaction table. Does that help?